# Difficulty with If statement within for loop to produce proper height value for SVG graph

Tags: php, if-statement, graph, svg

Repeat of a previous post, this time with the original code.

I'm creating a SVG candlestick graph but I'm having trouble producing the appropriate height.

The x value is determined by the **opening price**. In some cases the closing price is **greater** than the opening price, thus the position needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Because a negative value produces an error, i.e no rectangle at all, I need to take the difference between the **opening** and **closing** price and add this value to the x position.

Here is the code I have now. How would I effectively execute this type of adjustment?

I considered a foreach statement, but my php knowledge is limited and I kept running in to errors.

**EDITED**

X value is incremented. Y value is opening price.

```
    <?php

$open_price = array(5,10,15,20,25,30);
$closing_price = array (3,15,50,15,14);

$svg = '<svg id="main_graph" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="400" width="600" style="border:1px solid black;">';

$bars;

    for ($i=0, $count = count($open_price); $i<$count; $i++)

    {        
      $calculation = ($open_price[$i])-($closing_price[$i]);                    
      $bars .= '<rect x="'. $i * 5 . '" y="' . $open_price[$i] . '" width="20" height="' . $calculation . '" fill="blue"/>';                
    };

echo $graph = $svg . $bars . '</svg>';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Crazy Bars</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        #main_graph {margin-left: 100px;}

    </style>


</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the height to be the `absolute value` of the difference between closing price and opening price.  Use php's `abs()` function to calculate it.

```
$calculation = ($open_price[$i])-($closing_price[$i]); 
$abscalc = abs($calculation);
```

Then, if you wanted the bar to show in a downward direction for negative price movement, you'd want to adjust the y value as well.

```
$y = $open_price[$i];
if ($calculation < 0) $y = $closing_price[$i];
$bars .= '<rect x="' . $i * 5 . '" y="'.$y.'" width="20" height="' . $abscalc . '" fill="blue"/>';
```

This code will keep your x value constant, and cause the bar to show the price range.  The bar height will be the absolute value of the price difference, and the bar's y position will be the lower of the opening or closing price.

Comment: Ah man. I mistakenly put the opening price as the x value...assuming it is, would you recommend the using same method for adjustment?

I envisioned something like this but I made it more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  Can you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically, the difference between the two prices is the height. When the value is negative, I need to take the absolute value and adjust the position of that specific bar.